# How to test .net core 3.0 web api using azure ad implicit grant flow

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

In Angular/.net core 3.0 app I am using Azure AD implicit grant flow. The Web API uses authorisation and allows access based on roles (e.g. SuperAdmin, Admin and User roles etc). I need to write automated integration test for the Webapi (I can use a seperate client app too for testing). Any ideas which will be the appropriate grant flow for testing. I have read about [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) (Resource ownder password credentails) flow and its not recommended to be used. I can't use client credentails flow as this wont work with Authorisation. I will appreicate any links or examples.

Answer (score 0):

1.You should send a login request first(To enable the implicit grant flow, select the tokens you would like to be issued by the authorization endpoint…)：
[image]
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={your client id}&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure&scope=openid&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910
[image]

2.Getting access tokens silently in the background:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={your client id}&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910&prompt=none&login_hint={your-username}

3.You can also refer to the following documents, hope to help you：

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-angular

Answer (score 0):

Just if it helps someone, I did not find an alternate to get an access token to call the webapi which uses role based authorization (i.e. allow access to only users in certain AD groups) for my integration tests. So created few test users in the relevant AD groups and used resource owner password [credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) to get the access tokens and called the web api